# Special symbols not work in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uialertview

I have some problem with new line adding in UIAlertView. Category.rusname is NSString, containing "\n" symbols, smth like that "Phone1\n, Phone2]n". But instead of adding newline in the "\n" location alertView display string with "\n" symbol. And the string is displaying without nessesary new lines. There is the code.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: category.rusname message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", category.message] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ок" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
return;
```

[image]

Comment: could you please paste this category.message ?

Comment: `\n` is in fact supported by UIAlertView's label. Indeed, please post the string.

Comment: There's no reason for UIAlertView to convert "\n" strings to newlines, and I'm almost certain it doesn't. What if you wanted to display the actual string "\n"? The only place "\n" conversion takes place normally is when Localizable.strings is parsed at runtime (or during a build when it is converted to the binary plist format). If Localizable.strings is not involved, you will have to do this conversion yourself. Or just use real new lines in the first place.

Comment: @"Вызов полиции - 113\nВызов скорой помощи - 113 или 118\nВызов пожарной охраны - 115\nПомощь при ДТП - 116"

Comment: Is the NSString a literal (i.e. NSString *message = @"...\n...") or did you load it from somewhere?  You didn't write two slashes by mistake did you?

Comment: I also tried to call this way UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: category.rusname message:@"Вызов полиции - 113\nВызов скорой помощи - 113 или 118\nВызов пожарной охраны - 115\nПомощь при ДТП - 116" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ок" otherButtonTitles: nil]; and all works properly. But I need to common way not static string.

Comment: It works properly when you use a literal because the compiler will translate the "\n" at compile time. If the string originates from a database or user input or something where "\n" translation doesn't happen, you will need to do the translation yourself.

Comment: have you tried the `\x0a` instead of the `\n`?

Comment: holex, replacing \n to \x0a solve the problem. Mike Weller, you are right, but how I can translate special symbols manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIAlertView` will not convert "\n" substrings ('\' + 'n' in the input) into new lines. The only place this usually happens is when Localizable.strings is parsed (or built as a binary plist at compile time).

If `category.message` wasn't loaded from a strings file, you will need to perform this conversion yourself, or just use real newlines in the first place.

Comment: UIAlertView does in fact honor newlines in the message string. I do it all of the time. Or do you mean it will ignore the two separate characters \ and `n` if they happen to be in the string?

Comment: I mean it will not perform any conversion on the string you give it. If it contains '\' + 'n' as a substring, it will leave that untouched.

Answer (score -1):

On the assumption that `category.message` is already a string, then there is no reason to use `stringWithFormat:@"%@"`.  Just do `message: category.message`.

Comment: The message may contain characters like '%' which should NOT be interpreted as format placeholders. His current code is correct if the message is not a format string.

Comment: @MikeWeller Why would that matter?  If you aren't using `stringWithFormat:` then why would NSString attempt to interpret anything as a format string?  This answer is saying to use the string directly in the `message` field of the `UIAlertView` initializer.

Comment: Arg sorry, somehow I completely misread your answer. And it seems somebody else blindly downvoted you as well. I can't reverse my vote unless you edit your post. Humble apologies.

Comment: This answer may be a true statement but it has absolutely nothing to do with the actual issue.